# How to call an executable start a service from a MVC web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, service

I have a MVC4 app in which I need to init a long running process.  Currently, the code for this process is in a console app being installed as a service with topshelf.  I have the process checking a database every few seconds to see if it needs to be run, but that's not a solution.  I need a way for the MVC4 app to kick off the process and forget about it, but the process NOT be unloaded with the web app when the response is returned to the client.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why is polling the database not a solution?

Comment: If I want to return the report results to the client in a timely fashion, I either have to do it every second (which is unnecessary overhead and database access for the 23.5 hours it will not be used), or init the process externally.  I prefer not hitting the database 10,000 times per one process run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question, what you can do is, in the service (the class that's derived from ServiceBase), override OnCustomCommand:

```
private const int MY_CUSTOM_COMMAND = 140;
protected override void OnCustomCommand(int command)
{
    if (command == MY_CUSTOM_COMMAND)
    {
       ... Do stuff here ...
    }
}
```

You can then trigger the command in your service, from some external application along these lines:

```
private const int MY_CUSTOM_COMMAND = 140;
using (ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("MyTaskService", "ServiceMachine"))
{
   sc.ExecuteCommand(MY_CUSTOM_COMMAND);
}
```

That's the basic idea. Custom commands can be any value from 128-256 inclusive.

We use a similar system in our web app, which allows users to submit "jobs" that are then run by a windows service. The web app sends a command to the windows service to let it know a new job has been submitted. The service then goes to the DB to get the information about the job to execute.

Comment: Sorry for not checking it sooner.  This helped alot.  Now I have the problem that the server isn't allowing the service to be installed.  One more windows problem to deal with 8-S

Comment: @Difinity: If the process needs to be executed once on-demand, and occasionally on-schedule, then why not share the back-end code between the console application and the web application?  If the code is abstracted into its own module shared by the two applications then the web application doesn't need to invoke the service, it would just run the code as part of the web application.